# Different implementations of a C header file

Tags: c, header

How can I add multiple implementations to this header file:

MoveAgent.h

```
#ifndef _GAMEAGENT_
#define _GAMEAGENT_

#include "Defs.h"
#include "GameModel.h"

MoveDirection takeDirection(GameState *gs);

#endif _GAMEAGENT_
```

MoveAgent.c: Let's say that I have an implementation that will return a random move

```
MoveDirection takeDirection(GameState *gs) {    
    MoveDirection dir = DIR_NONE;       
    while (dir == DIR_NONE) {
        int index = arc4random() % gs->moves_total;     
        MoveDirection tempDir = gs->moves[index];       
        if (tempDir != oppDir(gs->car.direction)) {
            dir = tempDir;
        }
    }
    return dir;
}
```

What is practical way of having multiple implementations of that function?

As you might guess, I'm a Java programmer trying to make a basic game to learn C, so I'm trying to do this to simulate a Java interface.

Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on how you want to **choose** an implementation - at compile-time (i.e. globally) or at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This maybe jumping in a bit too much at the deep end, but:

You might be after a pointer to function plus several implementations of functions with different names that do the task.

#### MoveAgent.h

```
extern MoveDirection (*takeDirection)(GameState *gs);
```

#### MoveAgent.c

```
MoveDirection takeDirectionRandom(GameState *gs)
{
    ...
}

MoveDirection takeDirectionSpiral(GameState *gs)
{
    ...
}
```

#### Mover.c

```
#include "MoveAgent.h"

// Default move is random
MoveDirection (*takeDirection)(GameState *gs) = takeDirectionRandom;

void setRandomMover(void)
{
    takeDirection = takeDirectionRandom;
}

void setSpiralMover(void)
{
    takeDirection = takeDirectionSpiral;
}

void mover(GameState *gs)
{
    ...;
    MoveDirection dir = takeDirection(gs);
    ...;
}
```

So, somewhere along the line, you call one of the `setXxxxxMover()` functions, and thereafter you move using the mechanism set by the last of the two functions called.

You can also invoke the function using the long-hand notation:

```
    MoveDirection dir = (*takeDirection)(gs);
```

Once upon a very long time ago (1980s and earlier), this notation was necessary.  I still like it because it makes it clear (to me) that it is a pointer-to-function that is being used.

Comment: A small improvement - avoid repeating the function pointer prototype twice (once in the header, second time in the implementation). Use a typedef instead. 'typedef MoveDirection (*TTakeDirectionFunc)(GameState *gs);' and 'extern TTakeDirectionFunc takeDirection;' in the header, and 'TTakeDirectionFunc takeDirection;' in the implementation.

Comment: Just one more question before accepting the answer. Why do I have to use the 'extern' keyword if it also works without it? I guess it is good to do that, but why?

Comment: @Hexagon: good idea; not the naming convention I'd use, but it would work.  I wrote it out to see if it was an approximation to what was needed.  There's also a question of whether `takeDirectionSpiral()` and `takeDirectionRandom()` are declared.

Comment: Yes, I declared takeDirectionSpiral() and takeDirectionRandom() in the header file to make it work.

Comment: @wanstein: the `extern` in the header is necessary because otherwise you are multiply defining the variable. That is a 'common extension' to the C99 standard (Annex J), but is not strictly according to the standard with one definition. Headers should contain type definitions, enums, macros when necessary, and extern declarations of functions and (where necessary - as here) variables. It should not (normally) contain definitions of functions or variables (especially not static ones); it should also not contain initializers because those make the variable declarations into variable definitions.